# JQuery: Restore element content when clicked outside it

Tags: jquery, onclick

There are tons of questions on SO that address the issue of detecting clicks outside a designated element. However, none of them seem to serve my purpose in this scenario. Here's a function:

```
function rateit(){
    var cell = $('td.ratingcell');
    cell.dblclick(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var oldhtml = $(this).html();// restore this when clicked outside the cell
        var oldratingval = parseFloat($(this).find('span.ratingval:first').text(), 10);
        var oldratingcount = parseFloat($(this).find('span.ratingcount:first').text(), 10);
        var blanks = '<span id="5">☆</span><span id="4">☆</span><span id="3">☆</span><span id="2">☆</span><span id="1">☆</span>';
        $(this).addClass('editablerating');
        $(this).html("<span id='editrating'>" + blanks + "</span>");
        var clickedstar = $('#editrating span');
        clickedstar.click(function(f){
            f.preventDefault();
            var newrating = parseFloat($(this).attr('id'), 10);
            var deckid = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('td.ftable-deck-name:first').find('span.deck_id:first').text();
            updaterating(deckid, newrating, this);
        });
    });
}
```

Basically, this function makes a table cell editable for the user to update information inline. It works fine when the user does update something. However, I need to also handle situations where the user double-clicks the cell (element referenced by `var cell` in the function above) to edit but then clicks elsewhere (outside the cell) without any update or presses the Esc key. When that happens, I need to restore the contents of `cell` to `var oldhtml`.

Almost all the answers I have found on SO mention defining a global click handler bound to the body tag. But if I do that, how will I pass the value of `oldhtml` to that handler which will obviously be outside the function above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may searched a lot but this is some how relates to logic that why you didn't get any answer for it, you can try to use [data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) like,

```
.....
   e.preventDefault();
   $('table#tableId').data('oldhtml',$(this).html()); // restore this when clicked outside the cell
.....
```

now when clicking outside the cell you need to get the oldhtml from the table id
like,

```
$(document).on('click',function(e){
    var $elem = $(e.target);

    if((!$elem.hasClass('ratingcell') && // if it is not the td itself
          !$elem.closest('td').hasClass('ratingcell')))// and not its content
    {
        $td=$(elem).hasClass('ratingcell') ? $elem : $elem.closest('td.ratingcell'); // get the td
        if($('table#tableId').data('oldhtml')){
            $td.html($('table#tableId').data('oldhtml'));// set old content
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant idea about JQuery `data()`...didn't know about this awesome function. Just edit out the dots from your `hasClass()` functions as the class names go without dots as its argument.

Comment: WC... Yes, you are right. Removed the `.` from the `hasClass()`